# Edit meta tag for taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, meta-tags

I have around 15 categories in my site. I need different meta tags for each category page. How is that possible? I have tried using meta tag context.But it didn't worked. I have these modules enabled: Metatag and Page titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! I have found the option to edit the meta tags for taxonomy terms in Admin->Structure->Taxonomy->Category name->Edit->List
Then select the category which you want to edit.